# Calling C# click event without actually clicking the button not working

Tags: forms, visual-studio, c#-4.0, onclick

I have below code written inside C# Form application where I am trying to get `x,y` and `z` co-ordinates from Leap Motion device.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //controller.EventContext = WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current;
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
     }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Initialize the Controller object which connects to the Leap motion service
        // and captures the hand tracking data

        Controller controller = new Controller();

        //Get the most recent tracking data using the Frame object
        Frame frame = controller.Frame();

        for (int h = 0; h < frame.Hands.Count; h++)
        {


            // Initialize the Hand in the given frame
            Hand leapHand = frame.Hands[h];

            // Get the "Pointer" finger of current hand which refers to where a person is pointing
            Finger leapFinger = leapHand.Fingers[1];

            // Prepare a vector which will store the co-ordinate values of the tip of the pointer
            Vector currentPosition = leapFinger.StabilizedTipPosition;

            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(currentPosition.x);
            textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(currentPosition.y);
            textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(currentPosition.z);

        }

    }
}
```

However, I need to explicitly click the `button1` to display.
Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: It's unclear what your issue is.  Do you want the coordinates to display w/o having to actually click the button?

Comment: Why don't you call `button1_Click`?

Comment: I want to call the click event of button 1 without clicking the button manually.
I tried button1.PerformClick() , it doesnt work

Comment: @sous2817  yes exactly

Comment: How else to you want the code to execute?  Use a different event...there has to be something that triggers code to run.

Comment: What I believed is that when I run the code, the default constructor will get called which will call the Click event ...isn't it ? I know I am missing something, but can't figure out @sous2817

Comment: All you are doing is adding attaching the code to the event handler, not actually executing the code. So it's doing exactly what you told it to do, but not what you want.  Move the code to it's own method and call that method from the constructor.

Comment: @sous2817 appreciate your response. Can you edit that as an answer here to be more clear ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an overly simple example of one way to do it.  I'm not saying it's the best way, but you should be able to modify this sample code with your code.

In this example, there is a simple "HelloWorld" method that is called when the form is initialized as well as whenever you press the button.  Let me know if this gets you close to what you're after.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);

            HelloWorldTest();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HelloWorldTest();
        }

        private void HelloWorldTest()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, I didn't use your code because I don't have the Leap libraries installed and if there was a typo, I wouldn't be much help to resolve it.  Nonetheless, hopefully it gets you going down the right path.